# SQLite insert query error

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using following query to insert data into a SQLite database for Android.

```
INSERT INTO ServerData 
VALUES('404', '192.168.145.101', '1', '1', '1'),
      ('404', '192.168.145.101', '2', '1', '1')
```

But I am getting an error, the LogCat details are below:

> 11-22 15:14:56.588: E/Database(1609): Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x2e3e30 when preparing 'INSERT INTO ServerData VALUES('404','192.168.145.101','1','1','1'),('404','192.168.145.101','2','1','1')'.
>   11-22 15:14:56.618: W/dalvikvm(1609): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>   11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: INSERT INTO ServerData VALUES('404','192.168.145.101','1','1','1'),('404','192.168.145.101','2','1','1')
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at com.pcloud.fileshare.database.DBMethods.InsertToServerTable(DBMethods.java:228)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at com.pcloud.fileshare.dataAccess.commonMethod.updateServerTable(commonMethod.java:472)
>       11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):     at com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin$backgroundTask.doInBackground(userLogin.java:238)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin$backgroundTask.doInBackground(userLogin.java:1)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>                 11-22 15:14:56.648: E/AndroidRuntime(1609):   ... 4 more
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609): Activity com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40529668 that was originally added here
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40529668 that was originally added here
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:258)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin$backgroundTask.onPreExecute(userLogin.java:251)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.userLogin$1.onItemClick(userLogin.java:221)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
>       11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>                 11-22 15:15:00.059: E/WindowManager(1609):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The same query works fine in SQLite Expert but not in code

Comment: can you share your insert query code

Comment: Thanks for advice :-) actually i am trying each answer. now i get the desired one, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you cannot use the comma separator for multiple row insertion in the table. So, for your case you can try this :

```
INSERT INTO ServerData
      SELECT '404','192.168.145.101','1','1','1'
UNION SELECT '404','192.168.145.101','2','1','1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/1434631

You cannot use **comma separation** to insert multiple rows in **sqlite**..

It's better if you use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, i);
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, 0);
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
you cant insert multiple values seperated by comma

```
INSERT INTO ServerData VALUES('404','192.168.145.101','1','1','1')

 INSERT INTO ServerData VALUES ('404','192.168.145.101','2','1','1')
```

try this

```
 INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2') VALUES
    ('data1', 'data2'),
    ('data3', 'data4'),
    ('data5', 'data6'),
   ('data7', 'data8');
```

can be recast into sqlite as:

```
 INSERT INTO 'tablename'
  SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1',
         'data2' AS 'column2'
 UNION SELECT 'data3', 'data4'
  UNION SELECT 'data5', 'data6'
  UNION SELECT 'data7', 'data8'
```